# Regular Expression Numeric Range

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a text file , that I want to find some codes in it , each code consist a number of 3 digits + 7 capital letters 
examples : 374ANSKJDS  ; 3UKRHDPO ; 99RWLFOPE
my question how find these code by numeric range using grep or sed ?
for example I want to find codes starting from 750 to 900 ?

thanks

**EDIT**

**now that i did it using grep thanks to all , can somebody give the command to do it using awk under windows ?**

Comment: the best i can do is , [7-9][0-9][0-9] , which is wrong because it will find for example 999 that i dont want it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not compare the value of numbers using regexes. However, you can kind of work around this issue by specifying multiple patterns. For the interval you specified (750-900), you could use the following regex:

```
(7[5-9][0-9]|8[0-9][0-9]|900)[A-Z]{7}
```

Comment: Anyhow, this would also match text that has more than 7 capital letters (e.g. 750ABCDEFGHI). You have two alternatives: Replace "[A-Z]+" with "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" OR get to know the separation character (if there is one, like the trailing space in your example) and add it to the groups: "([7][5-9][0-9][A-Z]+ )"

Comment: Great! And thanks at @Tim for the range specification. Now I remember again. :)

Comment: sed and grep may have the start and end of word metasequences `\<` and `\>` or `\b` which will prevent more numbers and letters being included in the search result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such kind of regexp

```
((7[5-9][0-9])|(8[0-9][0-9])|(900))[A-Z]{7}
```

Comment: Oh.. seems that I have a duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

You can match all of them using:

```
\d{1,3}[A-Z]{7}
```

Since you want to match a range, you need to replace `\d{1,3}` part with something else for each range. Because the regular expressions work on strings, [you can not write](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) something like **[750-900]** to match a range. So, for the range [750-900], use this:

```
(7[5-9]\d|8\d\d|900)[A-Z]{7}
```